# Ocaml problem with recursively calling end function

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to call the last function in my code until I get the sum of last two lists.

The problem that I am trying to solve is:

> There is x cookies and n children. Return the list of cookies given to
> each child in a list, if you are giving each child n+1 cookies in each
> iteration. If at point you have less cookies than you should give,
> give the rest to the last child and stop.

Here's my code:

```
let rec spread a b c = 
  if a = [] then spread (List.tl a) (b-c) (c+1)
  else if List.tl a = [] then [List.hd a+c]
  else if c > b-c then List.hd a + c :: [(List.hd (List.tl a))+b-c]
  else 
    (List.hd a + c) :: spread (List.tl a) (b-c) (c+1)
```

This function works like this:

> spread (range 3) 11 1 ;; -> call
> int list = [1; 2; 3] -> output
>
> spread (range 3) 5 4 ;; -> call
> int list = [4; 1] -> output
>
> (range 3) call gives list with 3 zeros -> [0,0,0]

Now i made `list_sum` function that sums up lists:

```
let rec sum_list2 x y = 
  if x = [] then y
  else if y = [] then x 
  else 
    List.hd x+List.hd y :: sum_list2 (List.tl x) (List.tl y)
```

In the end I have to make some function that can be called like this:

> x (num of cookies) n (num of children)
>
> funct n x = ...

I made this, but it only goes up to sum 1st and 2nd list. I need to sum all of the lists until there are no cookies left, so it should recusively call spread until the end and sum all of the lists from spread.

```
let rec f5 x n =
  if n = 1 then [x] 
  else
    let brojac = 0 in
    let y = dijeli (range n) x 1 in
    if (sum(y) < x) then
      sum_list y (f5 (x - sum(y)) (brojac+n))
    else y
```

> https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hxra/2d5bd66b92b53c135b8ee255500c873f/raw/abff79ae3431a224a07a373551a2e09c19f874d4/cookies%2520and%2520children

Link to a full code which can be tested in ocaml online editor.

Comment: Please make sure that your code actually compiles and runs, and give some examples of expected output given various input, as well as the actual output if you can.

Comment: It does compile, i did not upload the whole code. I will do it right now.

Comment: With all of your calls to `List.hd` and `Lisst.tl` along with comparing to an empty list really suggest you should read up on pattern-matching.

Comment: Please also put all relevant information in the question itself. I see no reason to use a gist for this, unless you want to later remove the code, which is exactly why you shouldn't use external services for information that is essential to the question.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I will, I just started so I am pretty confused. Its not really similar to other languages I worked with.

glennsl - From now on I will try to do that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a very confusing way of naming variables and functions that hits you back. Try rewriting your code choosing better names that speak for themselves and I bet that you immediately find out what is the problem.

For example, in the function `f5` inside of your recursion you always call `dijeli` with `1` instead of `brojac`, moreover, the `brojac` variable never changes and is always equal to zero so that `brojac+n` is always equal `n`, so that on each iteration you increase your `n` by `0`.

You're also confusing the variable `n`, which you sometimes use as the number of children, e.g., `(range n)` and sometimes as the number of rounds that you  spend passing apples to children. Obviously, you need an extra variable in your recursive function.

To summarize, my advice is the following:

1. rewrite everything using consistent names for all variables, no `a`, `b`, `c`, `f5`. Remember, programming is first of all about understanding. Yours understanding of the problem, so your problem should be readable by a human.
2. Identify your induction variables - the variables that change on each step of recursion.
3. Indentify the loop invariant, i.e., the condition that has to be true for the loop to continue.

The good news, is that you're pretty close to the working solution, it just bad naming that gives you so much cognition burden that you can't get past the last step. So have a rest, choose proper names, and everything will work out.

P.S., to highlight exact places where you went wrong:

1. `let brojac = 0 in` no, it shouldn't be zero
2. `dijeli (range n) x 1` no, you're not passing one apple, but the number of apples that is split on this round
3. `f5 (x - sum(y)) (brojac+n)`, not `brojac+n` but the round number, for which you don't even have a variable.

Comment: Yeah the way i named variables might be weird but I was working on it by myself, didnt need to publish it anywhere. Anyway thank you for letting me know that. It might actually be easier to understand it even for me.  I was close, but probably it could not be done that way in Ocaml, i couldnt get working solution this way. I just didnt want to think of another way of approaching this problem. I will probably try that, then see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the specification

```ocaml
(* Immersion for target function *)
(* Non tail recursion *)
let rec spread_G cookies slot children = 
  if children==1 then [min cookies slot] 
  else if cookies < slot then 0 ::spread_G cookies slot (children - 1)  
  else slot :: spread_G (cookies - slot) slot (children - 1) ;;

(* P : children > 0 , cookies >= 0 *)
(* Target  function, Initial call *)
let spread cookies children = spread_G cookies (children + 1) children ;;
  

spread 20 4 ;; (* 20 cookies for 4 boys, each one ideally 4+1 = 5 . [5;5;5;5] *)
spread 16 4 ;; (* 16 cookies. Not enough for all  [5;5;5;1] *)
spread 12 4 ;; (* 10 cookies. Not enough even for last but one.[5;5;0;2] *)
```

I have to highlight that problem makes sense at least for one children. I can do also a tail recursion, but would be "harder" to read.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but maybe you did not understand the task, maybe i havent described it best. So the thing is if you have 3 children, first iteration should give [1,2,3];
2nd iteration should give them [4,5,6] in total [5,7,9];
Then if you have more cookies 3rd iteration should give them [7,8,9] in total [12, 15, 18].
So the result for call spread 45 3 should give output [12;15;18]

Comment: Else if you had 40, It should give everyone the same but the last 3rd iteration should give [7,8,4] instead of [7,8,9]  and the end result of calling spread 40 3 would be [12,15,14]
spread 30 3->[12;9;9] etc.

Comment: Aaaahhh... Now everything changes... It is a very beautiful problem now... I'm strugling with that .... Will let you know when ready...